# Submitting a form from a button in a modal?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a form which needs to have a confirmation alert/modal when it is clicked. Just something like "Are you sure you want to do this?". Then from the modal, there would be a "Submit form" button that would actually do the submission.

I know this is possible via ajax, but is there any other way to do this? Is it possible to do a normal form submit in this situation (from a modal)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');">
```

And if successful will submit form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `confirm` and attach it to the form's submit event. The `confirm` function gives the user a modal dialog with a yes and no option, and returns true or false.

```
$('#formId').submit(function() {
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
});
```

This will run when the form is submitted. Returning false will prevent the submission.